# make a simple script for hide/show use button in jquery

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm a beginner and not remember all script in jquery.

what i want to do is to make my hide/show div have more simple script.
not like my script:

```
<div id="aaa">
<div id="bbb">
<div id="ccc">

<button id="bt1">
<button id="bt2">
<button id="bt3">

$("#bt1").click(function){
    $("#aaa").show();
    $("#bbb").hide();
    $("#ccc").hide();
    });

and so on...
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function hideAll(){
   $("#bbb,#ccc,#aaa").hide();
}

$("#bt1").click(function){
//hide 
   hideAll();
//show 
$("#aaa").show();
});
```

that is if you want to show and hide element.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get much simpler than what you have.

You could combine your two `.hide` calls into one, but that's about it:

```
$("#bbb,#ccc").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is actually required but try this

```
<button id="bt1">
<div id="aaa">
<button id="bt2">
<div id="bbb">
<button id="bt3">
<div id="ccc">




$("#bt1,#bt2,#bt3").click(function(){
    $("#aaa,#bbb,#ccc").hide();
    $(this).next().show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can prepare your `div`s with a `data-` attribute to make it more easy. For instance:

```
<div id="aaa" data-btn="bt1">Content #1</div>
<div id="bbb" data-btn="bt2">Content #2</div>
<div id="ccc" data-btn="bt3">Content #3</div>

<button class="content-btn" id="bt1">Show #1</button>
<button class="content-btn" id="bt2">Show #2</button>
<button class="content-btn" id="bt3">Show #3</button>​
```

Now just follow my comments:

```
$('button.content-btn').click(function() {
    // [data-btn^=...] mean "attr data-btn start with..."
    // First hide all contents
    var contents = $('div[data-btn^=bt]');
    contents.hide();

    // Now store the button id clicked
    var show = $(this).attr('id');

    // Now find and show the content that combine with the button id
    var content = $('div[data-btn=' + show + ']');
    content.show();
});​
```

You can found a live example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r5VK/).

Comment: Hum... It isn't more simple, but you can create more buttons and contents without problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

With a few more HTML attributes you can make a single click function like this:

```
<div class="someclass" id="aaa"></div>
<div class="someclass" id="bbb"></div>
<div class="someclass" id="ccc"></div>

<button id="bt1" rel="aaa">show only aaa</button>
<button id="bt2" rel="bbb">show only bbb</button>
<button id="bt3" rel="ccc">show only ccc</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('.someclass').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
});
```

(Note: fixed the syntax error too!)

You could also use HTML 5 `data-` attributes, and `jQuery.data` to read them, instead of `rel`.